# DB2 composite index order for optimal read and write

Tags: database, db2, relational-database, database-performance, database-indexes

I have a table in a DB2 database currently having 20 million rows and growth rate is 2 million/quarter.This table is used for frequent insert and select (~2000 search and 600 insert per minute) but no updates at all. The search query has 4 columns FY, Q, C1, C2 as parameter in where clause

FY= Financial Year(e.g 201415, 201213, .....)

Q= Quarter(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)

C1= some column having 1.5 million unique char(10) values

C2= some column having 4 unique char(3) values

What will be the optimal composite index order with the above columns for faster  for insert and select. (consider index page caching and index tree scan time).
Most of the search and insert happens for only a particular FY and Q(i.e. current financial year and quarter) through out that quarter.

Moreover whether table partitioning and index partitioning will help for this use-case? Please comment in case any clarification is required.

Comment: Which DB2 platform and version are you using? Is your DB2 server licensed for data compression or BLU accelerated tables?

Comment: DB2 Version 9.7
Data compression :: yes

Comment: @FredSobotka BLU accelerated tables is not enabled on this instance as the same is for OLTP requirements not for analytical.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full definition of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question that can be answered in this context, because without complete details of your workload, the answer will always be **it depends**.  All solutions involve tradeoffs, it's a matter of finding what your users can live with.

Choosing a proper index design means understanding *all* of the queries that hit this table, and how frequently each query is run, and which queries must have a faster response time.